# After upgrade to 15.10: Sound crack on every boot

Tags: boot, sound, 15.10

I upgraded to 15.10 (from 15.04) via Software Updater. Now, every time I boot or reboot the system, there is an audible sound "crack" just before the boot splash.

Audio devices are the following:

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 64-bit.

It does not seem normal as it did not crack on boot with 15.04. Does anyone else have this problem and/or does anyone know how to fix it as it does not seem to be good for the speakers.

(What I am guessing is that the speakers are turned on too late or too early and hence, the cracking. Just like when you do sound engineering and you turn on the amps before the mixer. When the mixer is turned on, the speakers crack.)